# How to write more properties and methods for Process class

Tags: c#, inheritance, dll, system, extends

I want to add some properties and methods for Process class.

I've created an inherit class named `MProcess` like so:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process prc = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("ThankForRead.exe")[0];
MProcess process = new MProcess(prc);
```

If I have anything to access or communicate, write this code:

```
public void Kill(){
    this.prc.Kill();
}
```

But I don't like this way. I want to extends Process class, or partial then add properties, methods for that class it will more beautiful.
Extends is easy, just

```
public class MProcess : System.Diagnostics.Process
{
    //...blah blah
    public void GoAway()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bye");
        this.Kill(); // original method of process class
    }
    //...blah blah
}
```

But, how to get a `MProcess`? The static methods of Process class such as `GetCurrentProcess()`, `GetProcessesByName(string ProcessName)`, only return one or more process object, I tried to cast but it can't.

If my description is not clear, please let me know, I will try another way to let you understand what I say, sorry for my bad English.

Comment: well, Process is a native class, so you can't change it. you can inherit or extend it. i think what you need is inherit

Comment: Extension methods are probably the best way to add a few methods.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is "How I can cast automatically from specific type?", then you need to define on your `MProcess` class the operator [explicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4.aspx).

```
public class MProcess
{
    public static explicit operator MProcess(Process proc)
    {
        return new MProcess(proc);
    }
}
```

I suggest that you try to define it as [Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx).

```
public static class MyProcessExtensionMethods
{
    public static void GoAway(this Process proc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bye");
        this.Kill(); // original method of process class
    }
}
```

Then, you can use this method as:

```
Process prc = Process.GetProcessesByName("ThankForRead.exe")[0];
prc.GoAway();
```

Comment: Thank you, now I have the answer.

Answer (score 0):

well, for the most of the question i didn't understand what you mean, i think you'll have to get someone who knows English to translate what you want.

anyway, as i wrote in my comment, you can use inherit class like you did, or class extension and i'll add a [link here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx). I'll edit my question to make it more to your specific question if you'll tell me that's what you mean

as for the last part of the question:

> But, how to get a MProcess? The static methods of Process class such
>   as GetCurrentProcess(), GetProcessesByName(string ProcessName), only
>   return one or more process object, I tried to cast but it can't.

the static method `GetCurrentProcess()` will return a `Process` class. you can't cast classes just because you created an inherit class, no more then you can take a tree and say it's an apple tree just because an apple tree is a form of a tree

Comment: Yes, now I understand casting is impossible and have to write extension or keep what I've done before.

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing. Do not override Process class. Add Process Property in your MProcess Class & do operations on it. Like this :

```
public class MProcess
{
   //...blah blah
   //...

   private System.Diagnostics.Process myProcess;

   public System.Diagnostics.Process MyProcess
   {
       get {return myProcess;}
       set {myProcess = value;}
   }

   //...blah blah
}
```

Comment: I used this way first, I don't like the way mprocess.MyProcess.Kill() so I wrote a method Kill for MProcess